# All possible block diagonal forms for real valued $4\times 4$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form, block-matrices

This is one part of a larger question I'm trying to answer. The first part was determining all the possible Jordan normal forms for complex $4\times 4$ matrices, and the second part was determining the cyclic composition for each JNF described in the first part.

I have answered the first two parts, my primary confusion is what is the difference between "block diagonal form" and a Jordan normal form? And how do I find all possible block diagonal forms for real valued $4\times 4$ matrices

Also this isn't for any specific matrix, it's for any real valued $4\times4$ matrix.

Any help would be appreciated and I can try to elaborate more if needed, but there really isn't any more to the question than what I've described.